# What does the syntax for this url mean?

Tags: web, url, deployment, parameters

I am not familiar with urls or web development but I tried putting variable B in the url but all I get is a forbidden error message. I think it is due to the $ and {} parameters and I don't know what it means or what Iam supposed to do in regard to these parameters.

LINK: [https://puzzle.polymorph-aws.com/${B}](https://puzzle.polymorph-aws.com/$%7BB%7D)

I searched for the meaning of the dollar sign and curly brackets parameters on meta stack exchange and other sites but I haven't managed to find a conclusive answer as every suggestion that was there ended with the same forbidden error message.